# Writing all data from each row in CheckListCtrl

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

There is example code for the creation of `CheckListCtrl`. I took it from [here](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/advanced/).

```
import wx
import sys
from wx.lib.mixins.listctrl import CheckListCtrlMixin, ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin

packages = [('abiword', '5.8M', 'base'), ('adie', '145k', 'base'),
    ('airsnort', '71k', 'base'), ('ara', '717k', 'base'), ('arc', '139k', 'base'),
    ('asc', '5.8M', 'base'), ('ascii', '74k', 'base'), ('ash', '74k', 'base')]

class CheckListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, CheckListCtrlMixin, ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT | wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        CheckListCtrlMixin.__init__(self)
        ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin.__init__(self)


class Repository(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(450, 400))

        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        leftPanel = wx.Panel(panel, -1)
        rightPanel = wx.Panel(panel, -1)

        self.log = wx.TextCtrl(rightPanel, -1, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.list = CheckListCtrl(rightPanel)
        self.list.InsertColumn(0, 'Package', width=140)
        self.list.InsertColumn(1, 'Size')
        self.list.InsertColumn(2, 'Repository')

        for i in packages:
            index = self.list.InsertStringItem(sys.maxint, i[0])
            self.list.SetStringItem(index, 1, i[1])
            self.list.SetStringItem(index, 2, i[2])

        vbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        sel = wx.Button(leftPanel, -1, 'Select All', size=(100, -1))
        des = wx.Button(leftPanel, -1, 'Deselect All', size=(100, -1))
        apply = wx.Button(leftPanel, -1, 'Apply', size=(100, -1))


        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnSelectAll, id=sel.GetId())
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnDeselectAll, id=des.GetId())
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnApply, id=apply.GetId())

        vbox2.Add(sel, 0, wx.TOP, 5)
        vbox2.Add(des)
        vbox2.Add(apply)

        leftPanel.SetSizer(vbox2)

        vbox.Add(self.list, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.TOP, 3)
        vbox.Add((-1, 10))
        vbox.Add(self.log, 0.5, wx.EXPAND)
        vbox.Add((-1, 10))

        rightPanel.SetSizer(vbox)

        hbox.Add(leftPanel, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.RIGHT, 5)
        hbox.Add(rightPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        hbox.Add((3, -1))

        panel.SetSizer(hbox)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    def OnSelectAll(self, event):
        num = self.list.GetItemCount()
        for i in range(num):
            self.list.CheckItem(i)

    def OnDeselectAll(self, event):
        num = self.list.GetItemCount()
        for i in range(num):
            self.list.CheckItem(i, False)

    def OnApply(self, event):
        num = self.list.GetItemCount()
        for i in range(num):
            if i == 0: self.log.Clear()
            if self.list.IsChecked(i):
                self.log.AppendText(self.list.GetItemText(i) + '\n')

app = wx.App()
Repository(None, -1, 'Repository')
app.MainLoop()
```

How I can write in console (`self.log.AppendText(self.list.GetItemText(i) + '\n')`) data from 2nd and 3rd column for each  item?

Comment: yes, i find some methods in http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ListCtrl-class.html the method similar SetStringItem, for example GetStringItem

Comment: I give the same advice for all wxpython questions: why dont you guys check first the awesome collection of examples in the [wxPython docs and demos](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php#stable) from the official distribution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the item for the corresponding row/column and print its text:

```
item = self.list.GetItem(row, column)
print item.GetText()
```

Comment: Thank you. It’s exactly what I want.